# Android Bad UDP length > IP PAYLOAD length

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

I write a Android program to receive Multicast packets.
The code is in below.
The question is that I can receive the normal packets,
but I can't receive the packets with Bad UDP length > IP PAYLOAD length.
I guess that the bogus packets are drooped by someone.
How Can I receive the  bogus packets in Android ,Thanks!

[image: Wireshark]

```
public class SSDP extends Thread {

/**
 * Default IPv4 multicast address for SSDP messages
 */
public static final String ADDRESS = "239.100.10.100";
public static final String LOG_TAG = "SSDP";
public static final boolean DEBUG = false;

private SocketAddress mMulticastGroupAddress = new InetSocketAddress("239.100.10.100", 2060);
private MulticastSocket mMulticastSocket;
private DatagramSocket mUnicastSocket;
private NetworkInterface mNetIf;
private Context mContext;
private boolean mRunning = false;
private byte[] mFrameNumber, mNowFrameNumber, mSequenceNumber, mNowSequenceNumber;
private ByteArrayBuffer mReadBuffer;
private boolean mLast = false;

final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

public SSDP(Context ctx) throws IOException {
    mContext = ctx;
    mNetIf = Utils.getActiveNetworkInterface();
}

@Override
public synchronized void start() {
    mRunning = true;
    super.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        mMulticastSocket = new MulticastSocket(2060);
        mMulticastSocket.setLoopbackMode(true);
        mMulticastSocket.joinGroup(mMulticastGroupAddress, mNetIf);

        mUnicastSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        mUnicastSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        mUnicastSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Utils.getLocalV4Address(mNetIf),2060));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        UtilLog("Setup SSDP failed: " +  e);
    }

    while(mRunning)
    {
        DatagramPacket dp = null;
        try
        {
            dp = receive();
            //do somethins

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            UtilLog("SSDP fail: " + e); 
        }
    }
    UtilLog("SSDP shutdown.");

}


public synchronized void shutdown() {
    mRunning = false;
}

private void UtilLog(String message)
{
    if(DEBUG)
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);

}
private DatagramPacket receive() throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1500];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    mMulticastSocket.receive(dp);
    return dp;
}
}
```

Comment: Packets that are too long for the target DatagramPacket should be truncated, if received at all. Datagrams that are too large for the socket receive buffer might get dropped completely. How did the datagram get to be so big? You should generally restrict yourself to 534 bytes of payload for UDP, certainly not more than the PATH_MTU.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it.
It's a short packet issue in the kernel.
I modified the kernel code.
Here is the patch.

```
Index: net/ipv4/ip_input.c
===================================================================
--- net/ipv4/ip_input.c (revision 10665)
+++ net/ipv4/ip_input.c (working copy)
@@ -420,8 +420,8 @@

    len = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
    if (skb->len < len) {
-       IP_INC_STATS_BH(dev_net(dev), IPSTATS_MIB_INTRUNCATEDPKTS);
-       goto drop;
+       //IP_INC_STATS_BH(dev_net(dev), IPSTATS_MIB_INTRUNCATEDPKTS);
+       //goto drop;
    } else if (len < (iph->ihl*4))
        goto inhdr_error;

Index: net/ipv4/udp.c
===================================================================
--- net/ipv4/udp.c  (revision 10665)
+++ net/ipv4/udp.c  (working copy)
@@ -1631,13 +1631,13 @@
    saddr = ip_hdr(skb)->saddr;
    daddr = ip_hdr(skb)->daddr;

-   if (ulen > skb->len)
-       goto short_packet;
+// if (ulen > skb->len)
+//     goto short_packet;

    if (proto == IPPROTO_UDP) {
        /* UDP validates ulen. */
-       if (ulen < sizeof(*uh) || pskb_trim_rcsum(skb, ulen))
-           goto short_packet;
+//     if (ulen < sizeof(*uh) || pskb_trim_rcsum(skb, ulen))
+//         goto short_packet;
        uh = udp_hdr(skb);
}
```